# Swift String(format:array:) joins strings instead of composing them

Tags: php, arrays, string, swift

I have in my code the simple construct:

```
output=String(format:message, array: params)
```

that should format insert in the %@ of message the respective values of array params.
Yet, instead of doing it, it returns the elements joined by a comma as in:

> output=("Your subscription to %@ is due to expire in a week; renew it
>   now to miss no transit information!", [In Arrivo HD])

What might be the issue and how to format strings with the content of array in Swift similarly to php vsprintf?

Comment: Please also post the `message` and `params` contents.

Comment: simply remove the `array:`

Comment: Right, thank you very much, I did not expect that syntax to be fine. Anyway so far it work and that is good.

Comment: Please post a (small) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem, otherwise both question and answer are of no use for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by luk2302 the solution is to simply use:

```
 String(format:message, params)
```

Comment: For the record: I was the one who suggested that.

Comment: luk2302 suggested the solution, not me :)

Comment: Thanks for that too.